# adding to List (of Byte())

Tags: vb.net

The function requires a generic list (of Byte()) to be passed as agrs and I just cannot seem to get anything to add to this list.I require printdata(0) & (1) adding to it.

```
Dim printdata(1) As String


labelname = "WasNow"

printdata(0) = "9,99"
printdata(1) = "6.99"

Dim args = New List(Of Byte())

args.Add(Convert.ToByte(printdata))


ApplicationContext.CurrentDevice.Printer.Print(labelname, 1, args)
Frmscanprint.Show()
```

This is the working C# version of the code with only one item to add.

```
 private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.printNumber++;
            var args = new List<byte[]>() { Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Test #{0}", this.printNumber)) };
            if (!ApplicationContext.AllDevicesSelected)
            {
                ApplicationContext.CurrentDevice.Printer.Print("SamplePrint", 1, args);
            }
            else
            {
                PrintSampleForEachDevice("SamplePrint", 1, args);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The C# is converting a string while the VB is trying to convert a number in a string format, this is two different things. Convert.ToByte does not take an array. If you want to convert an actual number in string format, you'll have to set the culture properly since 9,99 and 6.99 are in two different format (dot vs comma). Maybe try to use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes in the VB

Answer (score 1):

The C# example you provided gets a single string and converts it to a byte array, assigning this array to the newly created list.

Your code is not doing the same thing. You are trying to convert a string array to a byte array. This conversion type is not allowed by the method you are trying to use. Even if it is possible, the result would be a single byte array with the entire content and not an array of byte array.

If you want to do the same thing as the C# code does, you shoud do it for each itm from your string array a time.

If you want to do the same thing as the C# code, you shoud do it for each single item from your string array. For example:

```
    For Each item As String In printdata
        args.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item))
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, This has fixed the issue I was having.